# Does $\lnot(A→B) ⊢ A→\lnot B$ in classical logic?

Tags: logic, solution-verification

Given $\lnot(A→B)$. Then $A˄\lnot B$.
Assume $\lnot(A→\lnot B)$. Then $A˄\lnot\lnot B$. By DN, $A˄B$. Also $A˄\lnot B (\text{reit})$. Contradiction, therefore, $\lnot\lnot(A→\lnot B)$ by indirect proof, which by DN is $(A→\lnot B)$. So $\lnot (A→B) ⊢ A→\lnot B$.

Comment: Why do you doubt your reasoning?  Do you know the "truth table" method that easily solves questions like this, especially with only two letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In propositional logic the following statements are equivalent:

- $p\vdash q$
- $\vdash p\to q$

So if you are still in doubt then you can just check whether statement:$$\neg(A\to B)\to(A\to\neg B)$$is a tautology by means of a truth table (as suggested in the comments on your question).